# flexbox дивами слева направо

Tags: html, css

Есть два дива, хочу, чтобы они шли по очереди слева направо.

```
<div class="about-us">

    <h2>О нас:</h2> 
    <p>TEXT</p>

</div> 

<div class="buy-invite">
    <h2>Покупка</h2>

<p>TEXT</p>

    <a class="button-buy" href="index.html">$</a>
</div>
```

Comment: и что, не идут, или что?

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

body>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-us">
  <h2>О нас:</h2>
  <p>TEXT</p>
</div>

<div class="buy-invite">
  <h2>Покупка</h2>
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <a class="button-buy" href="index.html">$</a>
</div>
```